# Error Code 1005. Can't create table : "takes" and "Teaches"

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1005

Would appreciate help. Can not create the "Teaches" and "takes" table.

```
CREATE DATABASE university;
use university;

CREATE TABLE classroom(
building VARCHAR(20), 
room_number INT,
capacity INT,
PRIMARY KEY (building,room_number)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Sales(
item VARCHAR(20),
color VARCHAR(20),
clothes_size VARCHAR(20),
quantity INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (item,color,clothes_size,quantity)
);

CREATE TABLE Department (
dept_name VARCHAR(20),
building VARCHAR(20),
budget INT,
FOREIGN KEY (building) references classroom(building),
PRIMARY KEY (dept_name,building,budget)
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
course_id VARCHAR(20)PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(20),
dept_name VARCHAR(20),
credits INT,
FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) references Department(dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE Instructor(
ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
neme VARCHAR(20),
dept_name VARCHAR(20),
salary INT,
FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) references Department(dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE section(
  course_id VARCHAR(20),
  sec_id INT,
  semester VARCHAR(20),
  year1 INT,
  building1 VARCHAR(20),
  room_number INT,
  time_slot_id CHAR,
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES Course(course_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (building1,room_number) references classroom(building,room_number),
  PRIMARY KEY(course_id,sec_id,semester,year1)
);

CREATE TABLE Teaches(
ID VARCHAR(20),
course_id VARCHAR(20),
sec_id VARCHAR(20),
semester VARCHAR(20),
year1 INT,
FOREIGN KEY (ID) references Instructor(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (sec_id) references section(sec_id),
FOREIGN KEY (semester,year1) references section(semester,year1),
FOREIGN KEY (course_id) references course(course_id),
PRIMARY KEY (ID,course_id,sec_id,year1,semester)
);

CREATE TABLE student(
ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
name1 VARCHAR(20),
dept_name VARCHAR(20),
tot_cred INT);

CREATE TABLE Takes(
ID VARCHAR(20), 
course_id VARCHAR(20),
sec_id INT,
semester VARCHAR(20),
year1 INT,
grade char,
FOREIGN KEY (ID) references student(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (sec_id) references section(sec_id),
FOREIGN KEY (semester) references section(semester),
FOREIGN KEY (year1) references section(year1),
FOREIGN KEY (course_id) references course(course_id),
PRIMARY KEY(ID,sec_id,semester,year1,course_id)
);
```

Comment: What is the question about ? What did you try ? Which are the errors ?

Comment: Foreign keys in MySQL need to have the same type definition as the primary keys to which they refer.  Going with this, you will see a number of problems with your current script.

Comment: Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'university.takes' (errno: 150)
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'university.teaches' (errno: 150) 
i fixed it anf its still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key references need to have the same types as the primary keys they refer to.  So consider:

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
    dept_name VARCHAR(20),
    building VARCHAR(20),
    budget INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (building) references classroom(building),
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_name,building,budget)
);

CREATE TABLE Instructor (
    ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    neme VARCHAR(20),
    dept_name VARCHAR(20),
    salary INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) references Department(dept_name)
);
```

The primary key for `Department` has three components -- `dept_name`, `building`, `budget`.  However, the reference has only one component.  They cannot match; the number is not correct, much less the types.

I would recommend that you use auto-incremented ids for your primary keys.  You can also specify uniqueness constraints, if you like.  So for this small example:

```
create table buildings (
    building_id int auto_increment primary key,
    building varchar(20),
    constraint unq_buildings_building unique(building)
);

create table classrooms (
    classroom_id int auto_increment primary key,
    building_id int,
    room_number int,
    capacity int,
    constraint fk_classrooms_building_id foreign key (building_id) references buildings (building_id)
) ;

create table Departments (
    department_id int auto_increment primary key,
    dept_name varchar(20),
    building_id int,
    budget INT,
    constraint fk_departments_building_id foreign key (building_id) references buildings(building_id)
);

create table instructors (
    instructor_id int auto_increment primary key,
    id varchar(20) unique,
    name varchar(20),
    department_id int,
    salary int,
    foreign key instructors_department_id foreign key (department_id) references departments (department_id)
);
```

This is just a small sample of your tables.  But the following are some rules that I follow:

- Table names are plural.
- They have a primary key which is the singular form followed by `_id` (or `Id`).
- Foreign key references are *only* to primary keys.
- To the extent possible, foreign keys and primary keys have the exact same name.
- Explicit constraints are given names.  The names follow a very precise naming convention.

I also added a `buildings` table.  It is referenced in at least two places, so it seems worthy of being its own entity.

This should give you some ideas on how to build your database.